# Building Boost on Solaris

Tags: c++, boost, solaris, sunstudio, cpp-netlib

Will Boost build in entirety on Solaris?

I'd like to know if anyone has success with this (specifically Proto/Spirit) before I go and pay for a support contract to patch Sun Studio 12.2 to the latest. I get a few errors and some look to have been resolved in patches, but it's not cheap to pay Oracle for support so I'd rather some hope that it will work before I do.

Right now, I'm just trying to use cpp-netlib on Solaris and decode some JSON fetched over HTTP using Boost Property Tree. It works fine on Mac OS X - so I'm hoping I can use the same code on Solaris.

Comment: Couldn't you just use GCC on Solaris?

Comment: would love to - but the product I'm integrating with means if I need to link with the Sun tool chain - I can build all my real work with GCC, expose a C interface and shim it in but thats quite a bit of work to reengineer now.

Comment: Sun C++ compiler has always been problematic. Avoid using it if possible.

Comment: I would avoid if possible. Unfortunately, it's not, so I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_48_0.html, you'll see two lists of compilers. The "primary" compilers are those that the release is tested against. There are no Solaris-based compilers there.

The second list is what the trunk is tested against (on a more or less daily basis). The Sun compiler v 5.10 is on that list.

Now, you can look at http://www.boost.org/development/tests/trunk/developer/summary.html, and find the test results for that compiler. From there, you can find the column for the Sun compiler, and check which tests are failing (and why).

However, it looks like pretty much all the spirit tests are failing on that compiler, so I wouldn't hold out much hope.

... Later ...
However, since you are using a different compiler than that, you might want to look at http://www.boost.org/development/running_regression_tests.html, which shows you how to run the regression tests using your installation. Then you can see how well boost works with your compiler.

Comment: Thanks for this Marshall - I was hoping there might be someone out there who might have worked some magic and gotten it working... but seemingly not.

Answer (score 2):

I've compiled up boost 1.54.0 on Solaris, using the Apache stdcxx 4.2.1 C++ library. There's a few diffs involved and a CLI recipe, but it's 99% built :) If I find a suitable place to upload the diffs I'll update this.

Intel Solaris 10 & 11

```
[...]
common.copy /usr/local/lib/libboost_timer.a
common.copy /usr/local/lib/libboost_wave.a
...failed updating 53 targets...
...skipped 37 targets...
...updated 10652 targets...
```

SPARC 10

```
[...]
common.copy /usr/local/lib/libboost_timer.a
common.copy /usr/local/lib/libboost_wave.a
...failed updating 49 targets...
...skipped 42 targets...
...updated 10649 targets...
```

The packages can be found on my packages archive at:

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/packages/solaris/sparc/

```
boost.1.54.0.SPARC.64bit.Solaris.10.pkg
boost.1.54.0.i86pc.Solaris.10.pkg
boost.1.54.0.i86pc.Solaris.11.pkg
```