# Openjdk8 in solaris 10:ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors

Tags: java, c++11, ld, solaris-10, solaris-studio

Am trying to build openjdk 8 in Solaris 10. [update 10]

```
/etc/release:
Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10x_u10wos_17b X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
```

Following https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html to build openjdk 8.
hotspot, corba,langtools,jaxp, jaxws build successfully. when jdk is built, am getting the below error.

```
## Starting jdk
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
__xargv                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
__xargc                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to /export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/idlj
gmake[2]: *** [/export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/idlj] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
__xargv                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
__xargc                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
__xargv                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
__xargc                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to /export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/objs/java_objs/java
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to /export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/jar
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
__xargv                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
__xargc                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to /export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/extcheck
gmake[2]: *** [/export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/objs/java_objs/java] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [/export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/jar] Error 2
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
__xargv                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
__xargc                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to /export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/appletviewer
gmake[2]: *** [/export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/extcheck] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [/export/home/preethi/check8/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/appletviewer] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [launchers-only] Error 2
gmake: *** [jdk-only] Error 2
```

When i was searching in net, i found this thread: [C++11 in Solaris 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150391/c11-in-solaris-10)

As stated in that, i have all the settings properly:

```
1) shown ld path as /usr/ccs/bin/ld
2) vi /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/CC-gcc/gcc_version.map
$mapfile_version 2

3) /usr/ccs/bin/ld -V
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.10-1.1514
4) /etc/release:
 Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10x_u10wos_17b X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
```

https://holtstrom.com/michael/blog/post/446/Shared-Library-Symbol-Conflicts-%28on-Solaris%29.html explains about linking in solaris. But unfortunately where i should change the order in openjdk source i couldn't get.
 i couldn't find any other thread regarding this. Please help me to resolve this.
Note: i don't have enough reputation(50) to comment in that above stackoverflow thread. so why created separate thread.

Comment: After installing SolarisStudio Version 12.3, all these issues are resolved. Can able to build openjdk8 in solaris 10 successfully.